# Gauss Jordan elimination method.

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve by Gauss-Jordan elimination method.
$$x + y  + z = 2 \\
x + 3y + 3z = 0 \\
x + 3y + 5z = 2$$

Putting this in reduced row-echelon form:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|r}
1 & 0 & 0 &  3 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &  -2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 &  1
\end{array}\right)
$$
So then
$\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
3 \\ -2 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and is 
therefore consistent system.

Is my final answer correct?

Comment: You can check your answer, up to consistency, by plugging your values in

Comment: WolframAlpha is a good place to go as well: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2By%2Bz%3D2%3B+x%2B3y%2B3z%3D0%3B+x%2B3y%2B5z%3D2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases} x+y+z=2 \\ x+3y+3z=0 \\ x+3y+5z=2 \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} x+y+z=2 \\ x+3y+3z=0 \\ 2z=2 \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} x+y=1 \\ x+3y=-3 \\ z=1 \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} x+y=1 \\ 2y=-4 \\ z=1 \end{cases}\begin{cases} x=3 \\ y=-2 \\ z=1 \end{cases}\\ \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \\ \quad \quad \\ \\ $$